# rviz zooming center

Tags: rviz, ros-kinetic, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running a ROS project, publising topics, and viewing in `rviz`. But I can't seem to figure out how to make the zooming center coincide with the camera of the robot. That is, I would like to put myself into the robot's camera frame and view the pointcloud plot as the robot is moving.

The plot seems to rotate around this yellow point when I use *left click* on `rviz`. Using *middle click* doesn't seem to move or translate the plot as I expect. Using *right click* also zooms in and out from this yellow point.

Could you please point me out what is this yellow point? If this is the zooming center, how can I make this coincide with the robot's camera frame?

[image]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338352/rviz-zooming-center/) by [ignite](https://answers.ros.org/users/49351/ignite/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2019-11-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-22**:
Please attach the image directly to the question. I've given you sufficient karma for that.

**Comment by [ignite](https://answers.ros.org/users/49351/ignite/) on 2019-11-22**:
@gvdhoorn, Thanks for that. I found that using `Shift + Left click` seems to work fine, but I do not know why middle click doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is called `Focal Point`, which can be set on the panel on the right side of `rviz`.

---

Originally posted by [ignite](https://answers.ros.org/users/49351/ignite/) with karma: 77 on 2019-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0